# Find Smallest contraction coefficient

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

I have been given the following function $f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{R}$:
$$
f(x)=\ln(x+2)-x
$$
And I have been asked whether it is a contraction or not, and if it is, I have to find the smallest contraction coefficient, such that $0<q<1$.

**Attempt**

Since $0<|f'(x)|<1$ for $(-1,1)$ we must have that the function is a contraction, and i would intuitively say that $\left|-\frac{2}{3}\right|=\frac{2}{3}$ is the smallest contraction coefficient.

**Doubts**

I have no concrete theorem or example to support my claim, and therefore I am skeptical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is differentiable
$$
\forall x \in [-1,1], |f'(x)|= |\cfrac{1}{x+2} - 1| = |\cfrac{-x-1}{x+2}| = \cfrac{1+x}{2+x}
$$
and 
$$
\forall x \in [-1,1], f''(x) = \cfrac{1}{(x+2)^2} \ge 0
$$
so $f'$ is growing.
And we have
$$
| f'(1)| = \cfrac{2}{3}
$$
So
$$
\forall x \in [-1,1], |f'(x)| \le \cfrac{2}{3}
$$
Therefore $\cfrac{2}{3}$ is indeed the smallest contraction coefficient.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :-)

Comment: You're welcome ;-)

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Because of the mean value inequality, you want to *maximize* $|f'(x)|$ for $x \in [-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Rasmus' realized that $L=\frac 23$ is the maximum value for $f'$ and therefore will work as a contraction constant. This was probably not the question. The question, I think, was about the possibility of getting a contraction constant $\tilde L < L$. The answer is no, it is not possible. If you consider a smaller constant you immediately get an interval of the form $[\xi, 1]$ where the contraction inequality does not hold.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-) Can you show the details about the mean value theorem and the interval which does not hold for any smaller interval? I have for long wanted to understand it :-)